# how to nest access tokens in javascript safely?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
FB.api({user-id},
    {
        "fields":"context",
        "access_token": anAccessToken
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
```

I am currently getting mutual friends via the context object. But in order for that to happen, I need to pass both the app_scoped_userid and my accesstoken from Oauth.

I feel uneasy putting these two strings in my client, since together anyone can use them to query any information the user has allowed my app permission to use.

Is there a better solution? (I have been contemplating moving the graph call onto the server, but that works against the light server-heavy client structure I am trying to achieve.)

Am I right to be worried?

Comment: how do you get the access token? are you just using FB.login?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's correct how you're using this functionality. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user.context/mutual_friends you should be able to run the following request:

```
/{friend_id}?fields=context{mutual_friends}
```

The Access Token (from the currently logged-in User) should be handled transparently by the JS SDK. I see no need to specify it for the request:

```
FB.api('/{friend_id}?fields=context{mutual_friends}', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

To the the `{friend_id}`, you'll need to query `/me/friends` first for the current User, and select a specific friend.

Comment: Sorry for the long response time. The problem with not supplying the access token. Will be that users who have a high security preference on FB wont show as a mutual friend unless the access token is supplied.